# Me sale esta excepción Se produjo una excepción de tipo "'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quiero eliminar en un GridView pero me aparece esa excepción, el código es el siguiente:

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Eliminar"))
            {
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                LinkButton btnNomenclatura = (LinkButton)gvListadoNomenclaturas.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lnkNomenclatura");
                int idNomenclatura = Convert.ToInt32(btnNomenclatura.Text);
                //resultado = db.ObtenerListadoNomenclaturas();
                resultado = db.ObtenerNomenclatura(idNomenclatura); 
                if (!resultado.Error)
                {
                    List<STCT004> Nomenclaturas = new List<STCT004>();
                    //Conversion de DataSet a List
                    Nomenclaturas = resultado.Datos.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(
                    dataRow => new STCT004
                    {
                        IdNomenclatura = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[4].ToString()),
                        IdProyecto = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[1].ToString()),
                        IdSistema = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[2].ToString()),
                        IdTipoNomenclatura = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[3].ToString()),
                        Descripcion = dataRow[5].ToString(),
                        Consecutivo = dataRow[6].ToString(),
                        Principal = Convert.ToBoolean(dataRow[0].ToString()),
                        IdReferencia = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[7].ToString()),
                        Estatus = Convert.ToBoolean(dataRow[8].ToString())

                    }).ToList();
                    if (Nomenclaturas.Count > 0)
                    {
                        hdnidNomenclaturaEstatus.Value = Nomenclaturas[0].IdNomenclatura.ToString();
                        lblidNomenclaturaEstatus.Text = "Nomenclatura" + Nomenclaturas[0].IdProyecto.ToString();
                        lblidProyectoEstatus.Text = "Proyecto"+ Nomenclaturas[0].IdProyecto.ToString();
                        lblidSistemaEstatus.Text = "Sistema"+Nomenclaturas[0].IdSistema.ToString();
                        lblidTipoNomenclaturaEstatus.Text = "TipoNomenclatura"+Nomenclaturas[0].IdTipoNomenclatura.ToString();
                        lblDescripcionEstatus.Text = "Descripcion: " + Nomenclaturas[0].Descripcion;
                        lblConsecutivoEstatus.Text = "Consecutivo: " + Nomenclaturas[0].Consecutivo;
                        lblPrincipalEstatus.Text = "Principal: " + Nomenclaturas[0].Principal;
                        lblidReferenciaEstatus.Text = "Id Referencia"+ Nomenclaturas[0].IdReferencia.ToString();

                        utilJS.ModalShow("ModalEstatus", this);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        utilJS.ShowMessage(true, "Error: La Nomenclatura no existe", this);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    utilJS.ShowMessage(true, resultado.MensajeError, this);
                }
            }
```

LA PARTE DONDE ME MANDA EL ERROR ES LA SIGUIENTE:

cuando llega a esta parte sale el error :

```
Nomenclaturas = resultado.Datos.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(
                    dataRow => new STCT004
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo general el error `System.FormatException` sucede al intentar convertir una cadena numérica en un tipo de datos numéricos, verifica los formatos, tal vez estas asignando mal un `dataRow`

Comment: Ya lo resolví, solo lo modifiqué
en lugar de: IdNomenclatura = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[4].ToString()),
Lo hice así: IdNomenclatura = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["IdNomenclatura"].ToString().Trim()),

PERO AHORA ME FALLA EN EL METODO DE ELIMINAR, ES IGUAL SOLO QUE AHORA ME MANDA ESTA EXCEPXION:

Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.ArgumentException' en System.Data.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Información adicional: La columna 'IdNomenclatura' no pertenece a la tabla STCT004.

No me reconoce el id

Muchas Gracias :)

Comment: Excelente, solo es que lo verifiques con tu 'dataRow' el id, tal vez escribiste el nombre mal, espero haber ayudado de algo.